# Android, How to create option Menu

Tags: android, android-menu

Here I tried to make option menu, but menu is not displaying on screen, so please guide me where am I doing mistake...

MenuTest.java

```
public class MenuTest extends Activity {
   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.more_tab_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.feeds:
        break;
    case R.id.friends:
        break;
    case R.id.about:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

And my XML file is more_tab_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/feeds"
    android:title="Feeds"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/friends"
    android:title="Friends"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:title="About"/>
</menu>
```

Please guide me,

Comment: Is this the complete activity code? Where's the onCreate method?

Comment: have you press `menu button` from emulator?

Comment: i also wrote the onCreate method, but after that i did not get menu in screen.

Comment: You can get more detailed explanation here: https://youtu.be/dXDkESYSFhA

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
public class MenuTest extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.more_tab_menu, menu);

        // return true so that the menu pop up is opened
        return true; 
    }
}
```

and don't forget to press the menu button or icon on Emulator or device

Answer (score 32):

please see :==

```
private int group1Id = 1;

int homeId = Menu.FIRST;
int profileId = Menu.FIRST +1;
int searchId = Menu.FIRST +2;
int dealsId = Menu.FIRST +3;
int helpId = Menu.FIRST +4;
int contactusId = Menu.FIRST +5;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(group1Id, homeId, homeId, "").setIcon(R.drawable.home_menu);
    menu.add(group1Id, profileId, profileId, "").setIcon(R.drawable.profile_menu);
    menu.add(group1Id, searchId, searchId, "").setIcon(R.drawable.search_menu);
    menu.add(group1Id, dealsId, dealsId, "").setIcon(R.drawable.deals_menu);
    menu.add(group1Id, helpId, helpId, "").setIcon(R.drawable.help_menu);
    menu.add(group1Id, contactusId, contactusId, "").setIcon(R.drawable.contactus_menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:
        // write your code here
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(MainHomeScreen.this, "Menu 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg.show();
        return true;

    case 2:
        // write your code here
        return true;

    case 3:
        // write your code here
        return true;

    case 4:
        // write your code here
        return true;

    case 5:
        // write your code here
        return true;

    case 6:
        // write your code here
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Change your `onCreateOptionsMenu` method to return `true`. To quote [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)):

> You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.

Answer (score 10):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.folderview_options, menu);
    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.locationListRefreshLocations) {
        Cursor temp = helper.getEmployee(active_employeeId);
        String[] matches = new String[1];
        if (temp.moveToFirst()) {
            matches[0] = helper.getEmployerID(temp);
        }
        temp.close();               
        startRosterReceiveBackgroundTask(matches);
    } else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.locationListPrefs) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferencesUnlockScreen.class));
        return true;
    }           
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: the option was invisible with the code. Inside onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu), I changed  return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)) to return true that made it visible.

Answer (score 10):

you can create options menu like below:

Menu XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Menu_AboutUs"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_about_us_over_black"
        android:title="About US"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Menu_LogOutMenu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black"
        android:title="Logout"/>
</menu>
```

How you can get the menu from MENU XML(Convert menu XML to java):

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_options_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

How to get Selected Item from Menu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.Menu_AboutUs:
                //About US
                break;

            case R.id.Menu_LogOutMenu:
                //Do Logout
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class AndroidWalkthroughApp2 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // show menu when menu button is pressed
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // display a message when a button was pressed
        String message = "";
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.option1) {
            message = "You selected option 1!";
        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.option2) {
            message = "You selected option 2!";
        }
        else {
            message = "Why would you select that!?";
        }

        // show message via toast
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace **return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);** with **return true;** in your **onCreateOptionsMenu** method
This will help

And you should also have the **onCreate** method in your activity

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers have covered the traditional menu used in android. Their is another option you can use if you are looking for an alternative

https://github.com/AnshulBansal/Android-Pulley-Menu

Pulley menu is an alternate to the traditional Menu which allows user to select any option for an activity intuitively. The menu is revealed by dragging the screen downwards and in that gesture user can also select any of the options.

Answer (score 0):

Android UI programming is a little bit tricky. To enable the Options menu, in addition to the code you wrote, we also need to call setHasOptionsMenu(true) in your overriden method OnCreate().
Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Nothing is tricky here. If you don't have a direct way, go back and study more or read the official documentation and understand thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

IF your Device is running Android v.4.1.2 or before,
the menu is not displayed in the action-bar.
But it can be accessed through the Menu-(hardware)-Button.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day
I was checked
And if You choose Empty `Activity` 
You Don't have build in Menu functions
For Build in You must choose Basic `Activity`
In this way You `Activity` will run `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Or if You work in Empty `Activity` from start
Chenge in `styles.xml` the

Comment: how do I change in styles.xml?