# Settings activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, application-settings

I am making an new android app and I would like to make a settings activity where the use can see about info and settings.
So on android devices you have buttons for settings or else it is presented on screen, when I click that button I do get a menu with the name settings (which I guess eclipse once made automatically) and I do have a activity_settings (as a launcher activity, I don't know if that has any influence or what it means actually) but how can I link the menu tab and the activity?
I mean that when in the menu is clicked on the settings-tab the activity opens.

Can you help me out?
Thanks in advance,
Ide

Comment: implement onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: Where do you mean? In the activity?

Comment: as in class ### extends #### implements onOptionsItemSelected? And do you know what launcher acitivity means?

Comment: no i meant override it... if you are new to android you should really read the Training guide on developer.android.com first.

Comment: I will do that tomorrow, so you mean after @override which code should I use?

Comment: read up on it. try something. if it doesn't work, then ask specific questions to help solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what Samarth is saying is true. Read the developer guide before you post questions here. A simple google search will give you links as well.

Here's a complete explanation on how to implement Menus and how to do it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Also a similar question on how to create an option Menu: [Android, How to create option Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439085/android-how-to-create-option-menu)