# Enter to the preferences screen using sub-menu

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-notifications

i use this code to set from a preferences screen, if i want show the notifications or not. The problem is that this code works only if i create a button to go on preferences screen. I want go on preferences with my sub-menu "settings" button and not a button inside my layout. Thsi is the code

```
       // prefer
         setPref.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){    
                @Override    
                public void onClick(View arg0) {     
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
                    Intent intent = new Intent(

                            MainActivity    .this, 

                            settings.class);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                }});         

            checkPref();

        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void checkPref(){

            SharedPreferences myPref 

            = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(

                    MainActivity.this);

            boolean pref_opt1 = myPref.getBoolean("pref_opt1", false); 


            if (pref_opt1){
                NotificationManager notifi = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle("Battery Informations")
                .setContentText("Batteria al")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small_not)
                //.setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
                .setTicker("Livello")
                .build();

                notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class); 
                PendingIntent penInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 , i , 0);
                notifi.notify(215,notification);
                } else {
                NotificationManager notifi = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notifi.cancel(215);
                }
        }



        @Override

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            checkPref();

    }
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

> I want go on preferences with my sub-menu "settings" button and not a
>   button inside my layout.

What you are looking for is [Options Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu), you can start learning about menu by reading some of the links below:

- [Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)
- [Android SDK: Implement an Options Menu](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-an-options-menu/)
- [Android, How to create option Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439085/android-how-to-create-option-menu)

Comment: Thanks.. But you mean entire code or only a part? From the `@Override    
                public void onClick(View arg0)...` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the question correctly:  instead of clicking a button, you would like to start your activity when clicking a menu item.  If so, then you can move the code from `OnClickListener.onClick()` to a method that handles menu click events [as described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu).

Comment: So you mean that the entire code i have to move it inside the `onOptionsItemSelected` method? but wich part of code have i to move?

Comment: Only code that start the settings.class activity - the one in  Button.OnClickListener.onClick()