# Relativelayout property issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to create my Toolbar layout like below image.

[image]

I written below code for create this view. Please see my `xml` Code.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_img_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_menu" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_textview_title"
            style="@style/textview_normal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar_default_img_menu"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar_default_img_search"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_img_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar_default_img_filter_tag"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_search" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_img_filter_tag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar_default_img_filter"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_filter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_img_filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_filter" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

After written this code i can see my view is correct in android studio preview but when i run my project it look like below image.

[image]

only left and right `imageview`  on correct position but my `textview` and other two `imageview` is not set on correct position after run this code.

May be problem with `android:layout_toEndOf` and `android:layout_toStartOf` property of `RelativeLayout`.

I don't know why this problem create.Thank you for help.

Comment: This is not the write way to do this .Checkout this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439085/android-how-to-create-option-menu , How to create an options menu

Comment: android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" add this line for another 2 ImageViews

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava i don't want to create menu

Comment: This is not the best way to do this, but when I use your xml, it seems to work fine (in the preview)

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal i already told in question it work fine in preview but after run it's not working

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal it's ok but u have any solution about this issue

Comment: You have applied circular relationship inside textview please remove it.

Comment: And to resolve above issue you can use linearlayout for right side view of your layout. Where Linearlayout would be horizontal aligned. and linearlayout should be alignparent end/right true,Are you getting my point?

Comment: When I run the app it seems to work fine, I think you should check out the answer from Tarak or Tomin (add toLeftOf and toRightOf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_img_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_textview_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:maxEms="50"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_img_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_search" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_img_filter_tag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_filter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_img_filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_filter" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Do changes as per your requirement by padding and margin to make a proper design.

Comment: with your answer all three image set on right side but text is overlapping on left image icon

Comment: Same problem text is still overlapping

Comment: In above textview width make it wrap_content.

Comment: Sorry,have you make it wrap_content for width?

Comment: Ohhh sorry @nikunj I did silly mistake there let me update my answer

Comment: Please check above updated answer. I did just toLeftof instead of toRightOf for textview

Comment: Not Working...bro

Comment: Ohh...can you please tell me what the issue you are facing now?

Comment: Textview is overlapping on menu icon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168636/discussion-between-sameer-jani-and-nikunj-patel).

Comment: Ohh why this occure could not understand because here it's working proper. No issue please check my above updated code again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `layout_alignParentRight` , `layout_toLeftOf` , `layout_toRightOf` ,`layout_alignParentLeft` instead of `layout_alignParentEnd` , `layout_toStartOf` , `layout_toEndOf` and `layout_alignParentStart` or use Both in the Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_img_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_textview_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toolbar_default_img_menu"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbar_default_img_search"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_img_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbar_default_img_filter_tag"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add_btn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_img_filter_tag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbar_default_img_filter"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add_btn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_default_img_filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add_btn" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screen Shot On Device]

Comment: @NikunjPatel : Try the Complete Code. I had Just Updated the Complete Code

Comment: Sorry, Bro. Check your code correctly. I'm Getting the result correctly. Check the Screen Shot. Which Device are you using for Testing? API 16 and Below Requires Start and End Values. Where 17 and Later Require Right and Left attribute Values

Answer (score 0):

you need to add them as action button on the appbar

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
android:layout_toLeftOf
```

along with

```
android:layout_toStartOf
```

and

```
android:layout_toRightOf
```

with

```
android:layout_toEndOf
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:layout_toLeftOf:
```

along with

```
android:layout_toStartOf:
```

and

```
 android:layout_toRightOf:
```

with

```
 android:layout_toEndOf:
```

because you need to support lower API versions.