# How to add App Store link to menu item?

Tags: java, android, app-store, menuitem

I can give link via Button.But I want to add a App store link to "rateus" in menu item.(please see attached image)here is the button code in MainActivity.java.This is not working for menu item.please help me.

```
//rateus button
        android.widget.Button ratebutton = (android.widget.Button) findViewById(R.id.id_rateus);
        ratebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            android.net.Uri.parse("market://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slsindupotha&hl=en")));
                }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e){
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            android.net.Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slsindupotha&hl=en")));
                }
            }
        });
//end rateus button code
```

here is my menu item image...
[rate us ite menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9l7o.jpg)

[image]

here is the code for rate us item

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/id_rateus"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_rateus"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Comment: this answers will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439085/android-how-to-create-option-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the menu functions, something like the code below.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds appModels to the action bar if it is present.
    this.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.share:

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBodyText = "Check it out. Your message goes here";
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject here");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBodyText);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Shearing Option"));
            return true;

        case R.id.id_rateus:
            try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,                                
android.net.Uri.parse("market://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slsindupotha&hl=en")));
                }catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e){
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            android.net.Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slsindupotha&hl=en")));
                }

            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..but I already have above code for adding to share app link like this link.
https://www.viralandroid.com/2016/05/adding-share-action-to-android-app.html    
how to add your part into this..

Comment: I've updated my code to show how the share and rateus menu items will be included in a switch statement

Comment: Glad to have helped, please accept my answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can handle a menu item click

1. Inflate the menu file

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_file, menu);
    return true;
   }
   ```
2. Then handle onCLick here

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   // Handle item selection
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case R.id.id_rateus:
    //handle onclick event for intent to playstore
    return true;
   default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
   }
   ```